# Cycle through autocomplete menu using tab

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

I am activating my autocomplete menu in vim using:

```
inoremap <C-@> <C-n>
```

and after it opened and only when it opened I would like to use the "tab" key to cycle through the menu. But when it isn't open I would still like to use the "tab" key to write normal "tabs". Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the following insert-mode mapping (see `:h mapmode-i`) in your `vimrc`:

```
inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
inoremap <expr> <S-TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<TAB>"
```

`:h pumvisible()` returns non-zero when popupmenu is visible and zero otherwise. `:h :map-<expr>` maps the key to the expression returned by the right hand side. And the whole expression is based on a ternary operator which ultimately states, map `<Tab>` to expression `\<C-n>` if popup-menu is visible and to expression `\<Tab>` otherwise.